# javascript to make sure two options are one apart

Tags: javascript, html

I have two select boxes that allows a user to select a valid day for example

```
<select name="valid">
    <option>monday</option>
    <option>tuesday</option>
    <option>wednesday</option>
    <option>thursday</option>
    <option>friday</option>
    <option>saturday</option>
    <option>sunday</option>
</select>

<select name="valid-2">
    <option>monday</option>
    <option>tuesday</option>
    <option>wednesday</option>
    <option>thursday</option>
    <option>friday</option>
    <option>saturday</option>
    <option>sunday</option>
</select>
```

what I need is a way to make sure if a user selects monday then they can not select monday or tuesday in the valid 2 select drop down.

However with out doing some thing like disabling the two days in valid two I am not sure how to do it.

I guess I could make the second select drop down after the user selects the first drop down.

So my question is how would you do it. and is there any simple and easy ways.

Comment: Can you use jQuery?  Would make this a lot easier....

Comment: If the legal values in the second drop-down depend on the value of the first, then yes, I would not populate the second until they pick the first one.

Comment: also, something like a drop-down of days of the week is probably best populated programmatically even in the first place.  Easy to do, can use localized names, etc.

Comment: @EthanBrown yes we can use jquery i guess

Comment: Just tell users the condition and validate when they are finished, otherwise you will tie yourself in knots trying to force them to do it the way you want. What if they select Monday in the first select, then Friday in the second, then go back and select Friday in the first. Do you disable the first once they've made a selection? How do they then go back to change the first if they want — must they reload or reset the entire form? Do you reset the second if they change the first? You really don't care what days are selected until they have finished, values in the meantime are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we get to use jQuery, here's my solution:

```
$(function () {
    var $one = $("[name='valid']"), 
        $two = $("[name='valid-2']"), 
        $both = $($one).add($two),
        $error = $("#error");

    $both.on("change", function () {
        var index = $one.find(":selected").index(),
            index_two = $two.find(":selected").index();

        //Note: will also catch sunday/monday combo (that's why it's % 6)
        if((Math.abs(index_two - index) % 6) < 2) {
            //Show an error of some sort, like this:
            $both.css("border", "1px solid red");
            $error.text("Dates cannot be less than 2 days apart!");
        } else {
            //Hide the error message:
            $both.css("border", "");   
            $error.text("");
        }
    });
});
```

I tossed in an error `<span>` after the options, you can see it in my JSFiddle demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/V7HMU/

As others have said, some sort of onsubmit-based validation is probably called for. It's a bit annoying to users to have to sort things out on the fly while the site is criticizing their every choice. But if you want to provide some helper text, this is a pretty easy way to do it.

I should note that this could be more efficient if you assigned IDs to the `<select>` drop downs and also provided some easier way to gauge values (like giving them numeric values). But I didn't want to mess with your HTML too much (aside from defaulting to a valid option).

Comment: @Russel - I generally advocate a "prevent and inform" style of validation; prevent the user from choosing incorrect combinations and inform them why, rather than complain at them after they've chosen something invalid. I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V7HMU/1/ to demonstrate -- disable the illegal choices so they can't be picked. Add a tooltip explaining why - my update to the fiddle is super-basic, as an example.  You'd have to also clear the title when re-enabling entries that become valid, and you'd have to do something about the current selection if it becomes invalid.

Comment: BTW, upvoting Pete's excellent answer; and don't forget to re-validate on the server no matter how helpful the client validation is.

Comment: @Pete—Fails if you select Tuesday of first week and Monday of second week.@Stephen—your "fiddle" shows how useless "prevent" is in this case, it's trivial to select invalid days.

Comment: @RobG Not failing for me... I wonder if it's an issue with my use of `.find(...).index()`... I never seem to be able to get that combo right. It would really be better if the options had numerical values we could compare instead of relying on jQuery witchcraft.

Comment: @Pete–no need for any jQuery, all that needs to be done is to compare the selectedIndex of the two select elements, that's it. See my answer (which could be done in half the code).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following that provides a hint to fix the second day if it's less than two days after the first. Note that it wraps around the week, so selecting Sunday in the first select means you have to select Tuesday or later in the first.

```
<script>
function validateSelect(el) {

  var msgEl = document.getElementById('errMsg');
  var errMsg = 'Second day must be at least two days after first day';
  var val1 = el.form.valid.selectedIndex;
  var val2 = el.form['valid-2'].selectedIndex;

  val2 = val2 < val1? val2 + el.options.length : val2;

  msgEl.innerHTML = (val2 - val1) < 2? errMsg : '';

}
</script>

<form ...>
<select name="valid" onchange="validateSelect(this);">
    <option selected>monday</option>
    <option>tuesday</option>
    <option>wednesday</option>
    <option>thursday</option>
    <option>friday</option>
    <option>saturday</option>
    <option>sunday</option>
</select>

<select name="valid-2" onchange="validateSelect(this);">
    <option selected>monday</option>
    <option>tuesday</option>
    <option>wednesday</option>
    <option>thursday</option>
    <option>friday</option>
    <option>saturday</option>
    <option>sunday</option>
</select>
<span id="errMsg"></span>
</form>
```